# Test if a value is unique in a vector in R

Tags: r, vector, unique

Let's assume the following example:

```
test<-c(1:5,3:7)
```

which gives

```
test
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 3 4 5 6 7
```

I would like to have an easy function that returns TRUE if the value is unique within the vector.

```
[1] TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
```

**What I tried:**

`unique(test)` only gives me back the unique values including those who are duplicated. 
`duplicated(test)` gives me back

```
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

which is obviously not the required result since the function tests for duplicated observations in sequence and the first occurrence is not counted as a duplicate. I could of course reverse the control sequence by including `fromLast = T` and create two vectors. Out of these two I could create a third that indicates true unique values...but this is rather to complicated.

`table(test)` allows me to compute the occurrence of each value

```
test
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
1 1 2 2 2 1 1
```

which brings me closer to what i want, but is still not the required result (a vector of the same length indicating whether it is unique within the vector or not.)

---

so anybody any idea how to do it easier?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The match operator `%in%` is very helpful:

```
!test %in% test[duplicated(test)]
```

Answer (score 4):

Your original suggestion to use `duplicated()`'s `fromLast = TRUE` switch combined with an OR operator seems a simple and elegant solution:

```
test <- c(1:5, 3:7)
test
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5 3 4 5 6 7

duplicated(test) # incorrect result
## [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

duplicated(test) | duplicated(test, fromLast = TRUE) # correct result
## [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

This play's nice when using data.table to perform operations by group, where the syntax makes it ambiguous if your variable name is the row value or the group column vector.

Answer (score 1):

```
test<-c(1:5,3:7)
isUnique <- function(vector){
                 return(!any(duplicated(vector)))
           }
isUnique(test)
```

The function will return true if values of vector are unique

Comment: Your function does not return the intended result. It should return a logical value for each element of a vector, determining if it is unique within the vector.

Answer (score 1):

Although quite a while since, an alternative. Let the numbers speak:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(DescTools)

set.seed(1789)
x <- sample(round(rnorm(1000), 3), 1e5, replace = TRUE)
bm <- microbenchmark(
            "!AllDuplicated(x)"             = !AllDuplicated(x),
            "!x %in% x[duplicated(x)]"      = !x %in% x[duplicated(x)]
      )
print(bm , unit="relative" , digits=3 , order="median" )

Unit: relative
                     expr  min   lq mean median   uq   max neval cld
        !AllDuplicated(x) 1.00 1.00 1.00   1.00 1.00 1.000   100   a
 !x %in% x[duplicated(x)] 1.44 1.43 1.16   1.45 1.52 0.143   100   a
```

So we see DescTools::AllDuplicated(), which by the way implements the formulated solution idea of joaoal, winning with x being numeric, but failing victim when dealing with characters (though only for the median, not the mean of runs).

```
z <- as.character(x)
bm <- microbenchmark(
            "!AllDuplicated(z)"             = AllDuplicated(z),
            "!z %in% z[duplicated(z)]"      = !z %in% z[duplicated(z)]
       )
print(bm , unit="relative" , digits=3 , order="median")

Unit: relative
                     expr  min   lq mean median   uq  max neval cld
 !z %in% z[duplicated(z)] 1.00 1.00 1.00   1.00 1.00 1.00   100   a
        !AllDuplicated(z) 1.09 1.09 0.97   1.06 0.68 1.16   100   a
```